# How to escape a string with single quotes

Tags: go, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

I am trying to unquote a string that uses single quotes in Go (the syntax is same as Go string literal syntax but using single quotes not double quotes):

```
'\'"Hello,\nworld!\r\n\u1F60ANice to meet you!\nFirst Name\tJohn\nLast Name\tDoe\n'
```

should become

```
'"Hello,
world!
Nice to meet you!
First Name      John
Last Name       Doe
```

How do I accomplish this?

`strconv.Unquote` doesn't work on `\n` newlines (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15893 and https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote), and simply `strings.ReplaceAll(`ing would be a pain to support all Unicode code points and other backslash codes like `\n` & `\r` & `\t`.

I may be asking for too much, but it would be nice if it automatically validates the Unicode like how `strconv.Unquote` might be able to do/is doing (it knows that x Unicode code points may become one character), since I can do the same with `unicode/utf8.ValidString`.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Go, but could you deserialise it with a JSON parser?

Comment: Thanks, @Matthew! It works: https://play.golang.org/p/Q6cy-anCwds

Comment: @CeriseLimón It's in Go and JSON: '\n' gets converted to a rune with a newline in it, and the same goes for '\u4E16'.

Comment: Single quotes are not used as string delimiters in Go or JSON.  Edit the question to state the syntax used.  Is it from Javascript, Vimscript, ???

Comment: @CeriseLimón https://yourbasic.org/golang/multiline-string/

Comment: Single quotes in Go define runes. a string is a slice of runes (EDIT incorrect: a string is a slice of bytes). A rune is a unicode code point.

Comment: The example in the question uses single quotes.  The article you linked uses backquotes. Which is it? A string is not a slice of runes.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. To clarify, I want to unquote a single quotes strings using Go code, not use single quote strings in Go code. The syntax is the same as Go but with single quotes.

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes - a string is a slice of bytes.

Comment: If the syntax is Go syntax with `"` replaced with `'`, then use `strconv.Unquote(strings.ReplaceAll(s, "'", "\""))`. Also, edit the question to state the syntax. A string is a sequence of bytes, not a slice of bytes.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that when `'` becomes `"`, I do not know if `"` in the results is originally `'` or `"`. For example, `'hello\''` becomes `hello\"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CeriseLimón came up with this answer, and I just put it into a function with more shenanigans to support `\n`s. First, this swaps `'` and `"`, and changes `\n`s to actual newlines. Then it `strconv.Unquote`s each line, since `strconv.Unquote` cannot handle newlines, and then reswaps `'` and `"` and pieces them together.

```
func unquote(s string) string {
        replaced := strings.NewReplacer(
            `'`,
            `"`,
            `"`,
            `'`,
            `\n`,
            "\n",
        ).Replace(s[1:len(s)-1])
        unquoted := ""
        for _, line := range strings.Split(replaced, "\n") {
            tmp, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + line + `"`)
            repr.Println(line, tmp, err)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, NewInvalidAST(obj.In.Text.LexerInfo, "*Obj.In.Text.Text")
            }
            unquoted += tmp + "\n"
        }
        return strings.NewReplacer(
            `"`,
            `'`,
            `'`,
            `"`,
        ).Replace(unquoted[:len(unquoted)-1])
}
```